# Adaptive cards extension button style

Tags: styles, adaptive-cards, spfx-extension

I'm writing custom adaptive card in typescript, and I need stylized buttons. Change font and background color is enough for me.. But I'm not fully understand how to implement custom renderer, can you help me with this?
I found similar post, but I'm not fully understand it, I need more detailed infos
[AdaptiveCards - How to customize the color and fonts for Actions on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62183449/adaptivecards-how-to-customize-the-color-and-fonts-for-actions-on-ios)

thx

i only found similar thread, but don't fully understand it

Comment: Can you give a bit more context about what you are trying to achieve? For some things just editing the host config is fine while other's need a custom renderer, both might be applicable depending on your use-case.

Comment: The card can have two buttons, but I can't control their background colour and font. This is my goal.. I don't know how to work with host config..

Comment: Where is the card hosted/rendered, in your own app?

Comment: its hosted on Sharepoint online

Comment: If its hosted inside Sharepoint (or MS Teams etc) you can not change the look and feel of buttons, this is only possible within your own apps.

Comment: yes, understand.. thanks for replies Tim!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have a proper answer here, it has been mentioned in other questions before but it is not possible to change the layout of anything AdaptiveCard related if you are not the host, rendering yourself.

The purpose of AdaptiveCards is that the host defines the look and feel so cards always feel as if they're part of the host's UI but you can define the content of the card.

If you want to customize card layout this can only be done if you host a card in your own website, webapp, etc which is totally doable.

In terms of any Microsoft App, Teams, PowerApps etc you can not change the look and feel of  AdaptiveCards other than what the cards come with.